# Why does hydration of alkene takes place in presence of an acid such as H3PO4 or H2SO4?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why acid is used? Can’t the hydration be done without acid? If not, why?

Comment: What do you know about the mechanism of the hydration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The acid is used as a catalyst. As can be seen from the mechanism below, the electron-rich double bond first attacks the positively-charged acid. The positively-charged hydronium ion is important because it is rather electrophilic and allows the nucleophilic pi bond to attack it, breaking the pi bond. This serves to initiate the reaction. Without an acid catalyst, the neutral water molecule would not be electrophilic enough for the pi bond to want to attack it, thus the reaction would not proceed.  [image]

(from http://slideplayer.com/slide/11423361/)

Comment: Great answer! It's worth mentioning how this electrophilic addition (hydration) works under acid catalyst by reducing the activation energy and abiding by Markovnikov rule as well. (This could be useful in comparing, the stability of carbocations when looking at primary, sec and tert-alkenes' hydration reactions).

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer : In the presence of an acid the water tends to behave as a base rendering hydrogen ions which can be attacked by the pi electrons. The rate of hydration would be way slower if acid is not used as there are lesser number of H+ ions.